# I have an error where there shouldn't be one in my unity project

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to modify Astars AIDestinationSetter to where if the player turns off their flashlight the enemy stops following the player, the problem is that I'm getting an error saying "The type or namespace 'Flashlight' cannot be found" I've tried all kinds of things but nothing seems to work, I always get some kind of error, here's the code for both scripts.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;


    public class FlashlightSwitch : MonoBehaviour
    {
        [SerializeField] private GameObject Flashlight;

        [SerializeField] private bool lightOn = true;

        [SerializeField] private float flashRate;

        public bool blobbySees;

        private float nextFlash;

        void Update()
        {
            if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
            {
                ToggleLight();
            }
        }

        void ToggleLight()
        {
            if (Time.time > nextFlash && lightOn == false)
            {
                nextFlash = Time.time + flashRate;

                Flashlight.SetActive(true);
                lightOn = true;
                print("Flashlight on");
                blobbySees = true;
            }

            if (Time.time > nextFlash && lightOn == true)
            {
                nextFlash = Time.time + flashRate;

                Flashlight.SetActive(false);
                lightOn = false;
                print("Flashlight off");
                blobbySees = false;
            }
        }
    }




using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

namespace Pathfinding {

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets the destination of an AI to the position of a specified object.
    /// This component should be attached to a GameObject together with a movement script such as AIPath, RichAI or AILerp.
    /// This component will then make the AI move towards the <see cref="target"/> set on this component.
    ///
    /// See: <see cref="Pathfinding.IAstarAI.destination"/>
    ///
    /// [Open online documentation to see images]
    /// </summary>
    [UniqueComponent(tag = "ai.destination")]
    [HelpURL("http://arongranberg.com/astar/docs/class_pathfinding_1_1_a_i_destination_setter.php")]
    public class AIDestinationSetter : VersionedMonoBehaviour {
        /// <summary>The object that the AI should move to</summary>
        public FlashlightSwitch flashlightSwitch;
        public Transform target;
        public Transform self;
        public Transform player;

        IAstarAI ai;

        void Start()
        {

        }

        void OnEnable () {
            ai = GetComponent<IAstarAI>();
            // Update the destination right before searching for a path as well.
            // This is enough in theory, but this script will also update the destination every
            // frame as the destination is used for debugging and may be used for other things by other
            // scripts as well. So it makes sense that it is up to date every frame.
            if (ai != null) ai.onSearchPath += Update;
        }

        void OnDisable () {
            if (ai != null) ai.onSearchPath -= Update;
        }

        void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D other)
        {
            if (other.CompareTag("Player"))
            {
                target = player;
            }

            

        }

        void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D other)
        {
            if (other.CompareTag("Player"))
            {
                target = self;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>Updates the AI's destination every frame</summary>
        void Update () {
            if (target != null && ai != null) ai.destination = target.position;
        }
    }
}
```

I tried every tutorial I could find and got "the type or namespace "FlashlightSwitch" could not be found" so I tried using a namespace, then I got "The type or namespace "Flashlight" could not be found", then I tried using an assembly definition folder which flooded me with errors no matter what I did, then I tried just putting them in the same folder (Astars Behaviors folder) and now we're here, no matter what I searched or did nothing helped.

I don't know where to add this at but I restarted my laptop and everything works fine now, not sure what was up but everything's good now

Comment: Which line gives you that error?

Comment: it says line 3, 7 so I guess either one, all it says is that the type or namespace "Flashlight" cannot be found

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what was wrong but I restarted my device and everything worked fine.